# How to render data (realtime/firebase) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database (realtime/firebase) created using Vue, and now I'd like to retrieve the data using React. I can see the data in the console, but I am unable to render all items, only the last one. This is what I've tried:

```
 const fetchDatabase = () => {
    db.on("value", snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(item => {
        let data = item.val();
        console.log(data);
        setSusi(data);
      });
    });
  };
```

and I'm trying to render it like this:

```
<ul>
        {Object.entries(susi).map(([key, value]) => {
          return (
            <li>
              {key}: {value}
            </li>
          );
        })}
        <hr />
      </ul>
      <button onClick={fetchDatabase}>pegar anamnese</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you set only the `last` item to the state:

```js
const fetchDatabase = () => {
    db.on("value", snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(item => {
        let data = item.val();
        console.log(data);
        setSusi(data);
      });
    });
  };
```

try it with something like this:

```js
const fetchDatabase = () => {
  const susis = [];
  db.on("value", (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((item) => {
      let data = item.val();
      console.log(data);
      susis.push(data);
    });

    // here we set all of them
    setSusi(susis);
  });
};
```

Comment: It worked! I did it just as you suggested with only small modifications:

 let data = JSON.stringify(item.val());

and

<ul>
        {susi.map((item, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
        })}
        <hr />
      </ul>

because of the error with Object not being able to be rendered. Thank you. Only thing left now is to format the data. Thank you

Comment: Sounds great :) It would be nice if you could mark the answer as accepted.